# AJAX login process, how to give an alert whether id or password is invalid?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, asynchronous, authentication

Hi I am relatively new to web developing.

I've used AJAX to process login step, and what I want to do is letting user know what value is wrongly input in either ID or Password.

For example, 
If a user makes a typo in ID, he will get an alert "Wrong ID" (in case there is no such ID in DB), or if user makes a typo in Password with valid ID, there should be an alert "Wrong Password!".

I haven't found reference yet but I expect this such process could be done by AJAX. Please give me an example or reference.

- updated

This is the code at front,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"login.do",
        type:"post",
        data: $('#loginform').serialize(),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(res){
            location.href="list.bo";  //Main Page
        },
        error: function(res){
            alert("Invalid ID or Password. Please check again");
        }
    })
})
```

})

Below is the code at Back,

```
    MemberBean result = dao.login(uid, pwd);
    if (result.getValidity()==1) {
        session.setAttribute("uid", uid);
        request.setAttribute("result", 1);
        forward.setRedirect(true);
        forward.setNextpath("/mypage/list.bo");
    } else if (result.getValidity()==0) {
        request.setAttribute("result", 0);
        forward.setRedirect(false);
        forward.setNextpath("/mypage/index.jsp");
    } else if (result.getValidity()==-1) {
        request.setAttribute("result", -1);
        forward.setRedirect(false);
        forward.setNextpath("/mypage/index.jsp");
    } 
    return forward;
```

And the below is DAO. So I was hoping that DAO can set of variable(result)'s validity according to its result (whether ID is wrong or password is wrong.) But for some reason, DAO occurs error and I currently blocked 'else if' parts.

```
try {
            conn = getConnection(); 
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MEMBER WHERE U_ID=? AND U_PWD=?");
            pstmt.setString(1, uid);
            pstmt.setString(2, pwd);
            result = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                loginresult.setValidity(1);
                return loginresult;
            } 
            else if (result.getString("U_ID")==null) {
                System.out.println("dao login fail1");
                loginresult.setValidity(-1);
                return loginresult;
            } else if (result.getString("U_ID")==uid&&result.getString("U_PWD")!=pwd) {
                System.out.println("dao login fail2");
                loginresult.setValidity(0);
                return loginresult;
            }
```

Comment: post your code so we can see what you have done and show you customized solutions

Answer (score 0):

You need to the customized message from the backend and then display it in the alert box

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/class/login.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
          if (data === 'Login') {
            window.location = '/user-page.php';
          }
          else {
            alert('Invalid Credentials');
          }
       }
   });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dont specify which is wrong](https://superuser.com/questions/1048747/username-or-password-is-incorrect-why-not-specify-which)

This doesn't answer your question, but does help you decide whether or not you want to develop this in to your application. Specifying that a user exists, but the password is wrong, can reduce the effectiveness of your app's security and motivate someone to find the password knowing that they have the username correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I've seen some pages that shows result either ID or password is wrong. Isn't this usual? I wonder if your comment goes for every occasion. I mean isn't there any way to do what I want to do while preventing the case that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For showing the error message for a user, you can simply show a bootstrap alert box(**toastr library**) when your ajax response contains an error message. and reset your form and it will be possible without page refresh.